# Affect entities/players in a 4 block radius without you getting affected

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I need a command that will effect players and entities in a 4 block radius with levitation, without yourself getting affected

I'm on bedrock.

(I apologize if I have bad english)

Answer (score 3):

Use the `/tag` command combined with the not operator.

---

##### Give yourself a tag!

The [`/tag` command](https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/tag_command.php) can be used to add and remove tags for entities; it's syntax is:

```
tag <entity> add <name>
```

I'd recommend giving yourself a tag that describes what you're using it for, simply for clarity purposes. So in this case, I recommend something like *immune*:

```
tag @s add immune
```

##### ‍ Use the radius and tag arguments.

You can limit which entities are impacted by a command's selector argument by providing additional arguments. In your case, you're interested in the radius and tag arguments which are `r` and `tag` respectively. For example, the following command will kill all entities within a 4 block radius of the command's execution position:

```
kill @e[r=4]
```

You can chain arguments together using a comma `,`:

```
kill @e[r=4,tag=killer]
```

##### ⛔️ Add the not `!` operator.

Since you want to run a command that impacts all players outside of a specific criteria (e.g. you're the only one unaffected), you'll need to specify the not operator when checking the tag:

```
kill @a[tag=!immune]
```

This, combined with your radius check will kill all players within a 4 block radius, that do **not** have the tag *immune*:

```
kill @s[r=4,tag=!immune]
```

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
give @a[name=!YOURNAME, r=4] dirt 1
```

Replace YOURNAME with your Minecraft username and when you run it, it should give everyone within 4 blocks (except from the username entered) a dirt block.